# How to see the participants' faces when I'm sharing my screen on Webex?

Tags: sharing, webex

When I start sharing my screen on Webex, in the beginning, I can see the faces of the other participants at the top of my screen, but after some time they just disappear. Could you please help me see all the participants during my presentation?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I cannot see the faces of the participants when I'm sharing my screen on Webex. What is not clear to you?